# How to convert list to expandobject key in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have a function in which i am getting data(array of objects) from db and then adding those objects of array one by one into a lit of type `ExpandoObject`

```
public async Task<List<ExpandoObject>> GetGroupWithMaxTickets(){
        List<ExpandoObject> topGroupsWithMaxTickets = new List<ExpandoObject>();
        dynamic ticketDetails = new ExpandoObject();
        var pipeline_tickets = new BsonDocument[]{
        new BsonDocument("$match", 
            new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "nsp", "/sbtjapan.com" }, 
                    { "datetime", 
            new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "$gte", "2019-12-03T00:00:34.417Z" }, 
                        { "$lte", "2019-12-03T24:00:34.417Z" }
                    } }
        }),
        new BsonDocument("$group", 
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", "$group" }, 
                { "totalTIckets", 
        new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) }
            }),
        new BsonDocument("$project", 
        new BsonDocument
            {
                { "_id", 0 }, 
                { "group", "$_id" }, 
                { "totalTIckets", 1 }
            }),
        new BsonDocument("$sort", 
            new BsonDocument("totalTIckets", -1)),
        new BsonDocument("$limit", 5)
        };
        var collection = await DbService.tickets.AggregateAsync<RawBsonDocument>(pipeline_tickets, new AggregateOptions {UseCursor = true, BatchSize = 500});
        await collection.MoveNextAsync();
        if(collection.Current.ToList().Count > 0){
            // ticketDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(collection.Current.ToJson());
            // ticketDetails.group = collection.Current.ToList()[0]["group"];
            // ticketDetails.totalTickets = collection.Current.ToList()[0]["totalTIckets"];
            Parallel.ForEach(collection.Current.ToList(), (ticket) => {
                Console.WriteLine("Ticket----"+ticket);
                dynamic groupWithTickets = new ExpandoObject();
                groupWithTickets = ticket;
                topGroupsWithMaxTickets.Add(groupWithTickets);
            });
        }
        return topGroupsWithMaxTickets;
    }
```

But it throws an error like this

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject>.Add(System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)' has some invalid arguments)
```

I want that my function must return array of objects of type `List<ExpandoObject>`

How can i do this in c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have changed the question, following is the answer that should resolve your matters.

**How to NOT work with ExpandoObjects**

I tested this on my system and got it to reproduce the same results as you are getting. Following is the failed try:

```
    dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
    List<ExpandoObject> listOfEmployees = new List<ExpandoObject>();
    employee = "someStrangeString";
    listOfEmployees.Add(employee); // ERROR !!!!
```

and just as expected, i get the following error on Add.

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject)' has some invalid arguments
>     Source=
>     StackTrace:

**Corrected way of ExpandoObject use**

Following is the method that will take care of the issues with Adding it to the list.

```
    Parallel.ForEach(collection.Current.ToList(), (ticket) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ticket----" + ticket);
        dynamic groupWithTickets = new ExpandoObject();
        groupWithTickets.users = ticket; //<---- Assign ticket to users element.

        topGroupsWithMaxTickets.Add(groupWithTickets);
    });
```

**What was done to fix it?**

When you are working with ExpandoObjects, you have to think of dictionary type of a deal. When you declare ExpandoObject, you have to dynamically assign the value to an element (that you define).

[Example from MS site:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) shows the proper use of ExpandoObject

```
        dynamic employee, manager;

        employee = new ExpandoObject();
        employee.Name = "John Smith";
        employee.Age = 33;

        manager = new ExpandoObject();
        manager.Name = "Allison Brown";
        manager.Age = 42;
        manager.TeamSize = 10;
```

Hopefully this resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this;

```
dynamic ticketDetails = new ExpandoObject();
ticketDetails.user = collection;

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticketDetails);
```

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look of it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
dynamic ticketDetails = new ExpandoObject();
ticketDetails = Json(new users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(collection.Current.ToJson()));
```

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look of it

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes, i used an array **arr** that holds one of the elements. If you need that array to be part of ExtendoObject with first element being users, you can create a Json object and set the array as value to the "users" element.

```
    dynamic ticketDetails = new ExpandoObject();

    JArray arr = new JArray();
    arr.Add(@"[{""name"": ""Alex"", ""age"": 21}]");

    JObject o = new JObject();
    o["users"] = arr.ToString();
    ticketDetails = o;

    // output: { "users" : [{"name" : "Alex", "age" : 21}]}
```

Comment: i have updated my question please have a look of it